# collection instancing not showing the object

Tags: instances, collections, duplicate

I'm currently working on a project where I have to replicate a diamond-encrusted surface. I created a new group ("GEM4") for the diamond ("Cylinder") in order to generate a collection instance, but when I try to generate the new instance only the empty shows up and the object itself doesn't get replicated. I've tried creating the collection again and making sure the diamond object is inside but nothing is working. I'm attaching screenshots to better explain myself.

I really have no idea what's going on, probably some settings I have to switch up but I can't really find the solution. Please heeelp

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file with the collection that you want to instance only?

Comment: Here!! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eCtMX89NU9aC22S3kQdSfHGmLAU0gNaf/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Your instance is actually here, but very far away from the empty, so you need to zoom out a lot to see it:

[image]

Why that? Because the empty will be created as far away as the original objects of the collection are far from the world center. Here your collection object (here cylinder) is far from the world center, so when you'll create an instance of the collection, the object will be far away from the instance empty.

You have 2 ways to fix it, either move the original object closer to the world center, or select your object, right click > *Set Origin > Origin to Geometry* (because for the moment the origin is out of the object), put your 3D cursor on the object (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*), go into the *Object Properties* panel > *Collections > GEM4 > Set Offset from Cursor*:

[image]

Comment: Ah!! I'm blind hahaha, the problem is fixed now. Thank you so much for your help, really appreciated :)